# Angular trap upgrading issue on datepicker

Tags: angular-strap

After upgrading from angular strap 2.2.4 to 2.3.1 my datepicker does not work anymore. Is there a known issue about this?

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was that after upgrading that you cannot use readonly,
once i removed that i was a for away